# perfect width of background images on different screen sizes and devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, background-image

I wonder how to fit background images perfectly like Apple.com does on different screen sizes and devices (see Example)

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7Pdj.png)

The red circles (edges of the MBP) are always on the edge of the screen on smaller devices but on larger screens, more width of the image is displayed.

The image is 2560x882 and the width of the MBP is 1045px.

I also noticed that on very high resolution they swap the image to a larger one that is double the size. How can I achive this?

Comment: maybe they use different size of images depending on the width of the screen or on the type of device, using a mixture of media-queries and javascript.

Comment: You need to use svg images to fit on any size of the screen and any resolution.

Comment: @sissy yeah I think media-queries is the way to go...

Answer (score 0):

For images you can use

```
img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; }
```

For background image you use:

```
div { background-size:cover; } /* background-size: "contain" | "100%/100%" | "100%" is also an option according to requirement. */
```